# Exception: Cell reference out of range (last line)

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to sort a column of information in my sheet, however I keep getting an error when I run the program. I preform the function twice in my script. The attempt works but the second attempt does not. It says that its out of range but when I crosscheck it seems as though the parameters are correct. I have attached a portion of my below as reference:

---

```
//Section C: Filtering data by current month into third sheet.
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName('Summarized Data');
  var beginDate_current = sheet3.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var endDate_current = sheet3.getRange("B3").getValue();

//Section D: Setting filter criteria based on dates in Data Overview sheet.
  var filteredData = rngData.filter(function(row)
  {var date = row[0]; return date >= beginDate_current && date <= endDate_current});

//Section E: Setting filtered data into Current Month table in Summarized Data sheet.
  sheet3.getRange("B7").getDataRegion().offset(6,0).clearContent();
  sheet3.getRange(7,3,filteredData.length,filteredData[1].length).setValues(filteredData);
  sheet3.getRange(7,3,filteredData.length,filteredData[0].length).sort([{column: 3, ascending: true}]);

//Section F: Filtering data by previous quarter into third sheet.
  var beginDate_quarter = sheet3.getRange("B5").getValue();
  var endDate_quarter = sheet3.getRange("B6").getValue();

//Section G: Setting filter criteria for quarterly months. 
  var filteredData = rngData.filter(function(row)
  {var date = row[0]; return date >= beginDate_quarter && date <= endDate_quarter});

//Section H: Setting filtered data into Previous Quarter table in Summarized Data sheet.
  sheet3.getRange("I7").getDataRegion().offset(6,0).clearContent();
  sheet3.getRange(7,9,filteredData.length,filteredData[0].length).setValues(filteredData);
  sheet3.getRange(7,9,filteredData.length,filteredData[0].length).sort([{column: 7, ascending: true}]);
```

---

[sheet3 reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dca0u.png)

(error applies to last line in code)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By the way, what is your showing image? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I have a set of data populates on one sheet and I am attempting to display it on a second sheet and sort it by dates given a range input. Then I want to the dates to be sorted chronologically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName('Summarized Data');
  var beginDate_current = sheet3.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var endDate_current = sheet3.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var filteredData = rngData.filter(function(row)
  {var date = row[0]; return date.valueOf() >= beginDate_current.valueOf() && date.valueOf() <= endDate_current.valueOf()});
  sheet3.getRange("B7").getDataRegion().offset(6,0).clearContent();
  sheet3.getRange(7,3,filteredData.length,filteredData[1].length).setValues(filteredData);
  sheet3.getRange(7,3,filteredData.length,filteredData[0].length).sort([{column: 3, ascending: true}]);
  var beginDate_quarter = sheet3.getRange("B5").getValue();
  var endDate_quarter = sheet3.getRange("B6").getValue();
  var filteredData = rngData.filter(function(row)
  {var date = row[0]; return date.valueOf() >= beginDate_quarter.valueOf() && date.valueOf() <= endDate_quarter.valueOf()});
  sheet3.getRange("I7").getDataRegion().offset(6,0).clearContent();
  sheet3.getRange(7,9,filteredData.length,filteredData[0].length).setValues(filteredData);
  sheet3.getRange(7,9,filteredData.length,filteredData[0].length).sort([{column: 7, ascending: true}]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work.

Comment: I will need more of the function and sample data to debug the problem.  Also be aware that I will not follow links to spreadsheets.  Post data in a table that I can copy